# What is the centroid of the area bounded by x^3 and 10-x?

Tags: calculus, integration, centroid

I understand what the problem is asking, but I don't fully understand the concept behind it.

I know the formula for x bar is 1/A times the integral of x(f(x)-g(x)),

and that the formula for y bar is 1/A times the integral of 1/2(f(x)^2 - g(x)^2)

I just don't understand how to determine which function is on top or to the right. I successfully found the area by adding the integral of x^3 from 0 to 2 to the integral of x-10 from 2 to 10

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you draw a picture?

Comment: yes, I used desmos online to see what the graph looked like